# What are the arguments of webdriver.Firefox() and their significance

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = False
webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=cap, executable_path='D:/nchaurasia/Python-Architect/connect2tech.in-Selenium-Python/FF/geckodriver.exe')
```

The above code works perfectly fine.
Now i am trying to understand the **selenium.webdriver.Firefox** i.e. find the documentation for Firefox which comes from webdriver.

I have checked the following links: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/api.html
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/py-modindex.html

I have googled a lot but cannot find the documentation for 
    **selenium.webdriver.Firefox**

Actually I am looking for something similar to https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/
where i can access package, classes and methods in classes.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems you have access to everything you wanted, can you update the question with what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: @DebanjanB As i mentioned I want to know what all acceptable argument for selenium.webdriver.Firefox object that I am creating. Is this information documented somewhere. I also want to know what are the possible classes/modules inside selenium.webdriver. 

I checked the existing document but cannot find it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Firefox (
firefox_profile: NoneType=None,
firefox_binary: NoneType=None,
timeout: int=30,
capabilities: NoneType=None,
proxy: NoneType=None,
executable_path: str="geckodriver",
options: NoneType=None,
log_path: str="geckodriver.log",
firefox_options: NoneType=None
)
```

See if this helps https://kite.com/python/docs/selenium.webdriver.Firefox

Answer (score 0):

As per your question and comment update here are the relevant details :

### selenium.webdriver.Firefox()

[**selenium.webdriver.Firefox()**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver) is defined as :

```
class selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver(firefox_profile=None, firefox_binary=None, timeout=30, capabilities=None, proxy=None, executable_path='geckodriver', options=None, log_path='geckodriver.log', firefox_options=None, service_args=None)
```

Where :

- `firefox_profile` : Refers to the instance of *FirefoxProfile* object or a string to be used. If undefined, a fresh profile will be created in a temporary location on the system.
- `firefox_binary` : Refers to the instance of *FirefoxBinary* or full path to the *Firefox* binary to be used. If undefined, the system default Firefox installation will be used.
- `timeout` : Refers to the time to wait for *Firefox Browser* to launch when using the extension connection.
- `capabilities` : Refers to the dictionary of *Desired Capabilities*
- `proxy` : Refers to the the *proxy settings* to use when communicating with Firefox via the extension connection.
- `executable_path` : Refers to the full path to of the *GeckoDriver* binary to use for Firefox 47.0.1 and greater. If undefined, defaults to picking up the binary from the system path.
- `options` : Refers to the instance of *options.Options*
- `log_path` : Refers to the location to log information from the driver.

### classes/modules within selenium.webdriver

The list of classes/modules within *selenium.webdriver* can be found at [**Python Module Index**](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/py-modindex.html)

```
selenium.webdriver.android.webdriver    
selenium.webdriver.chrome.options   
selenium.webdriver.chrome.service   
selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver 
selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains 
selenium.webdriver.common.alert 
selenium.webdriver.common.by    
selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities  
selenium.webdriver.common.html5.application_cache   
selenium.webdriver.common.keys  
selenium.webdriver.common.proxy 
selenium.webdriver.common.service   
selenium.webdriver.common.touch_actions 
selenium.webdriver.common.utils 
selenium.webdriver.firefox.extension_connection 
selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary   
selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile  
selenium.webdriver.firefox.options  
selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver    
selenium.webdriver.ie.webdriver 
selenium.webdriver.opera.webdriver  
selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.service    
selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.webdriver  
selenium.webdriver.remote.command   
selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler  
selenium.webdriver.remote.mobile    
selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection 
selenium.webdriver.remote.utils 
selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver 
selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement    
selenium.webdriver.safari.service   
selenium.webdriver.safari.webdriver 
selenium.webdriver.support.abstract_event_listener  
selenium.webdriver.support.color    
selenium.webdriver.support.event_firing_webdriver   
selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions  
selenium.webdriver.support.select   
selenium.webdriver.support.wait
```

Comment: actually what i want to know is that after doing the following

"from selenium import webdriver"

I want to know that directly inside webdriver what classes/method etc. are present.

Comment: @NareshChaurasia I have included the list of _classes_ in _webdriver_ within my answer. However providing the list of _method_ will make the question too broad.